# Error building dapper in a .net v5.4 project on visual studio team services hosted build agent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops, dnx, azure-pipelines-build-task

I recently set up a very basic .net web project and used dapper in my repository to access a database. It works and builds with no errors on my local computer, but when i attempt to build on VSTS, i get an error saying that certain packages are not compatible with .net framework v5.4 or v5.0 (tried a few different frameworks in an attempt to get it to build.)

Here's the project.json file in question that contains dapper. This builds and restores without any issues locally on my computer:

```
      {
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "ProjectPOC.Core.Implementations Class Library",
    "authors": [ "CBergeron" ],
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",
    "dependencies": {
      "ProjectPOC.Core.Infrastructure": "",
      "ProjectPOC.Core.Models": "",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Dapper": "1.50.0-beta9"
    },
    "frameworks": {
      "net451": {
        "dependencies": {

        }
      },
      "dotnet5.4": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
          "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
          "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
          "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
          "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

When This project is built on the VSTS hosted build agent, i'm running the preinstall.ps1 script that's commonly being used here:

```
# bootstrap DNVM into this session.
  "bootstrapping dnvminstall..."
  &{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}
   "finished bootstrapping"

   "Loading global.json"
  # load up the global.json so we can find the DNX version
  $globalJson = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\global.json -Raw -ErrorAction Ignore | ConvertFrom-Json -ErrorAction Ignore
  "finished loading global.json"  


  if($globalJson)
  {

      $dnxVersion = $globalJson.sdk.version
    "setting DNX version.. to $dnxVersion "
  }
  else
  {
      Write-Warning "Unable to locate global.json to determine using 'latest'"
      $dnxVersion = "latest"
  }

  # install DNX
  # only installs the default (x86, clr) runtime of the framework.
  # If you need additional architectures or runtimes you should add additional calls
  # ex: & $env:USERPROFILE\.dnx\bin\dnvm install $dnxVersion -r coreclr
  "installing DNX"
  & $env:USERPROFILE\.dnx\bin\dnvm install $dnxVersion -Persistent
  #& $env:USERPROFILE\.dnx\bin\dnvm install $dnxVersion -r clr
  #& $env:USERPROFILE\.dnx\bin\dnvm install $dnxVersion -r coreclr
  #& $env:USERPROFILE\.dnx\bin\dnvm use $dnxVersion
  & $env:USERPROFILE\.dnx\bin\dnvm list
    "finished DNX install  "


    "DNU restoring....."
   # run DNU restore on all project.json files in the src folder including 2>1 to redirect stderr to stdout for badly behaved tools
  Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\src -Filter project.json -Recurse | ForEach-Object { & dnu restore $_.FullName 2>1 }

  #dnu restore
  "finsihed DNU restore"
```

This script is installing the following dnx based on the build logs, which matches my dnvm listing on my local machine:

```
2016-05-19T03:45:19.1014995Z installing DNX
    2016-05-19T03:45:19.9042850Z Downloading dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2 from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
    2016-05-19T03:45:22.7176602Z Installing to C:\Users\buildguest\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2
    2016-05-19T03:45:22.7766619Z Adding C:\Users\buildguest\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2\bin to process PATH
    2016-05-19T03:45:22.8456619Z Adding C:\Users\buildguest\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2\bin to user PATH
    2016-05-19T03:45:22.8826599Z Native image generation (ngen) is skipped. Include -Ngen switch to turn on native image generation to improve application startup time.
    2016-05-19T03:45:23.0276682Z Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
    2016-05-19T03:45:23.0346603Z ------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
    2016-05-19T03:45:23.0356615Z   *    1.0.0-rc1-update2 clr     x86          win                  
    2016-05-19T03:45:23.0586614Z finished DNX install  
    2016-05-19T03:45:23.0596622Z DNU restoring.....
    2016-05-19T03:45:23.2796607Z Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16609
    2016-05-19T03:45:23.4785866Z   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    2016-05-19T03:45:23.5821917Z   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json 123ms
    2016-05-19T03:45:23.6261910Z   GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/
    2016-05-19T03:45:24.4737562Z   OK https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/ 847ms
    2016-05-19T03:45:24.4787560Z   GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/
    2016-05-19T03:45:25.1793928Z   OK https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/ 700ms
```

After it finishes the restore from nuget, during the build it throws errors like this for the package library with dapper in it and anything that references it:

```
       Unable to resolve dependency System.Collections.NonGeneric 4.0.1-rc2-24027
 ...
 2016-05-19T03:47:01.3562201Z ##[error]Platform\POC\ProjectPOC.Web.API\src\ProjectPOC.Core.Implementations\project.json(0,0): Error NU1002: The dependency System.Collections.NonGeneric 4.0.1-rc2-24027 in project ProjectPOC.Core.Implementations does not support framework .NETPlatform,Version=v5.4.
 2016-05-19T03:47:01.3602187Z      5>C:\a\1\s\Platform\POC\ProjectPOC.Web.API\src\ProjectPOC.Core.Implementations\project.json : error NU1002: The dependency System.Collections.NonGeneric 4.0.1-rc2-24027 in project ProjectPOC.Core.Implementations does not support framework .NETPlatform,Version=v5.4. [C:\a\1\s\Platform\POC\ProjectPOC.Web.API\src\ProjectPOC.Core.Implementations\ProjectPOC.Core.Implementations.xproj]
```

Again this is building, running, deploying to azure, etc flawlessly from my local machine in VS2015, so i feel like it has something to do with the hosted build agent and it's dnx/dnvm/nuget setup. Is there something that i need to add to the build agent or something i need to do to the dnvm/nuget install to get the correct versions of everything? I also uploaded my nuget.config to the build agent and that also didn't help. I can provide more of the logs on request.

my local dnvm list looks like this:

```
  Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
  ------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
         1.0.0-beta8       clr     x64          win
         1.0.0-beta8       coreclr x64          win
         1.0.0-beta8       coreclr x86          win
         1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          win
         1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          win
         1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          win
         1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          win
    *    1.0.0-rc1-update2 clr     x86          win             default
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can provide any help with this or has run into a similar issue before with the new .net stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met this issue before and it did not work on my local machine. And I get it work by use the "1.50.0-beta8" version for Dapper instead of "1.50.0-beta9". beta8 use older dependencies then beta9.

This issue seems to be caused by the change here: [Rename "dotnet" to "NETStandard"](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/4435f9f2776ae007e05f4454675e56cf76a51975) but I haven't got time to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you! the simplest answers are the best ones. Moved back to "Dapper": "1.50.0-beta8" and it started working on the build host. Doesn't explain why it works on my machine but i can move forward with what i'm doing.